# seaborn doesn't draw the errorbar

Tags: python, seaborn

It's my first time to use seaborn. I want to draw a picture with errorbar like the example of [errorband_lineplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html).

What I want:

[image: what I want]

But what I get is a picture without errorbar:

[image: what I get]

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "./training_data.csv"  # the path I store my data
data = pd.read_csv(path)  # read my data
sns.lineplot(x="i_ep", y="reward", data=data, errorbar="sd")  # draw the picture

plt.show()
```

I think I have set the argument, but it doesn't work.
Please tell me what should I do.

To show the structure of my data here is the file I recorded when I trained the RL model:

```
      i_ep  steps      reward
0        0     98   47.928611
1        1     33   90.713333
2        2     67   83.200198
3        3    179  -20.885040
4        4     29   93.702619
    ...    ...         ...
4995  4995     10  100.436667
4996  4996      7  100.245000
4997  4997      2  100.100000
4998  4998      6  100.228333
4999  4999      7  100.245000
[5000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hello, what's inside training_data.csv ? Can you provide a dataset description?

Comment: For seaborn to draw error bars, seaborn needs the original data and be able to calculate the errors itself. Also, it needs the x-values to appear multiple times with different y's. Depending on your goal, you might want to round the x-values. If each x-value only appears once, the error is zero. Anyway, without reproducible test data, your question is a bad fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: sry, I have added the struct of my data

Comment: if you inspect the dataframe that the example seaborn gives, it is completely different to the data in the question.  For a start there are twice as many columns and half of those are categorical data. . .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is possible to inspect the dataframe in the example link given in the code.

```py
print(fmri)
```

the data structure looks like this:

```
     subject  timepoint event    region    signal
0        s13         18  stim  parietal -0.017552
1         s5         14  stim  parietal -0.080883
2        s12         18  stim  parietal -0.081033
3        s11         18  stim  parietal -0.046134
4        s10         18  stim  parietal -0.037970
...      ...        ...   ...       ...       ...
1059      s0          8   cue   frontal  0.018165
1060     s13          7   cue   frontal -0.029130
1061     s12          7   cue   frontal -0.004939
1062     s11          7   cue   frontal -0.025367
1063      s0          0   cue  parietal -0.006899

[1064 rows x 5 columns]
```

We can see 5 columns, 3 of which are categorical data (`subject`, `event` and `region`).

For avoidance of doubt, the code is this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

# Load an example dataset with long-form data
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")

# Plot the responses for different events and regions
sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal",
             hue="region", style="event",
             data=fmri)
```

Where `fmri` is the data that would be equivalent to the given `training_data.csv` file in the question.

If you use data in this shape (structure), then the chart will looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems the timepoint appears more than once for the same value, I would try that. Thank you!